# Android file not found exception for txt file

Tags: java, android

I am trying to read in a .txt file for my Android application but I keep getting the file not found exception regardless of what path I put in. Right now I have the absolute path in for the FileReader as follows:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:\\BuzzWord\\testing.txt"));
```

However, this is the exception I am getting:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\BuzzWord\testing.txt (No such file or directory)
```

I have double checked the file name and path, below is a picture of details.

[image: text file details]

All help is appreciated thanks!

**EDIT:**

I have the following permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: can you post the permissions that you have included in the AndroidManifest ?

Comment: Android doesn't usually have a path like "D:\...".  More like "/sdcard/...".

Comment: @jesses.co.tt I added the permissions in the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Android is made on top of Linux, you need to use the linux path separators (a forward slash `/`). The ones you're using now are Windows separators (a backslash `\`) (also, `D:\` is a Windows drive letter). You're code should look something like this:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(context.getFilesDir(), filename)));
```

[From here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html)

Comment: Now I get the following `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/user/0/com.testdomain.buzzword/files/testing.txt (No such file or directory)`. What I am trying to do is store the contents of the file in the array list, or search the file for a specific string in my app.

Comment: Did you write the file previously in your app? if so, where?

Comment: I open it for the first time through the BufferedReader, and then I have code to read the text file line by line. I just don't know what directory to store my text file in so that it can be read.

Comment: Store it in `context.getFilesDir()`. This is the default allocated folder for your application.

Comment: That would be the `/data/user/0/com.testdomain.buzzword/files` path I assume? How would I navigate to this path to paste the file in it? I can't seem to find it.

Comment: I assume so. When writing to the file, use `context.getFilesDir()` as the filepath and append the name of the file. (also, don't forget to close the file when done writing to it)

Comment: Actually, I am trying to read from the file, check if my string exists in the file

Comment: If it's coming from another app you (usually) can't read it. However, if you're pulling it down from a server, be sure to put it in your files dir.